# We'll be fixing up some images due to changes in imgur policies

Tags: discussion

As per the [main meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/388556/imgur-tos-change-on-may-15th-could-cause-the-loss-of-thousands-of-stackexchange) - there's a risk of images hosted on the 'main' imgur instance (as opposed to the stack exchange one) being deleted due to changes in their TOS. Images uploaded anonymously will be deleted, and there's no real way to check which images fall under that.

[There's only 21 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/pets/query/1742595/top-posts-with-non-stack-imgur-images-order-by-of-views) that need going through and fixing  according to SEDE - there may be some disruption to the front page as these are fixed.

Some of these need resizing, and I'm not sure what to do with some of the gifs yet, since its not a simple upload - so its best effort first.

If you want to assist in fixing it - let us know, and if you're a user with only suggested edit abilities and the edits are not validated, you can generally find me or other users in the [site chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10964/the-litter-box) to assist. Considering the number of posts, going slow ought to be fine however and there's no rush to get these fixed.

Comment: "there's no rush to get these fixed" - well, you have until May 15th.

Answer (score 1):

I've a listing of posts as per SEDE as below. Feel free to add any we've missed.

| Link | Status |
| --- | --- |
| [Strange dark scabbing near cat's nose](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/19265) | Completed |
| https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/2561 | Completed |
| https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/20190 | Partial |
| [How smart are rabbits?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/6281) | Completed |
| https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/7204 | Completed |
| [What is this bump on my cat's lip?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/19322) | Completed |
| https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/11308 | Completed |
| [Dark and scabby spot on my kitten's nose](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/28440) | Completed |
| [Do the skin scales developing on my dead kitten provide any clues to what may have caused its death?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17235) | Completed |
| https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1704 | Completed |
| [Do cats usually attack when their human owner exhibts excited behavior?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17085) | Partial |
| [How to administer topical eye ointments to flat faced dog who bites](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/13726) | Completed |
| [Can cats see optical illusions the same way we can?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/3058) | Completed |
| [Noisy canister not pumping](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/19851) | Completed |
| [What is the difference between salmon/fish oil for a cat and a human?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/9405) | Completed |
| ["Scratch" on my cat's head?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/28337) | Completed |
| https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/15356 | Completed |
| [How to mitigate adopted stray's fear of other cat?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17615) | Completed |
| [Dachshund Head Swelling](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/17485) | Completed |
| [Can goldfish eat sea lettuce?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/19361) | Completed |
| [Dog continually licking thighs](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/20901) | Completed |

For both the partially fixed posts - they contain *massive* gifs/gifvs that I wasn't able to resize effectively. There's a back up copy of both remaining images on the 'regular' imgur instance on the internet archive